# Multiple event listeners (with SSCCE)

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

I am creating a game and I have two classes that are listening for events. I have a `Menu` class that listens for `ActionEvent`s on the `JFrame.getContentpane()` `Container` and an `InputManager` that listens for `KeyEvent`s, `MouseEvent`s and `MouseWheelEvent`s on the `JFrame` itself. When the menu closes, the `blocked` variable is set and it is blocked from performing any actions. Like this:

```
private boolean blocked;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (!blocked)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}

public void blockActionEvents(boolean blocked)
{
    this.blocked = blocked;
}
```

Also the `InputManager` is unblocked, so that the game can listen for any (mouse, key, mousewheel) events and perform the corresponding `GameAction`.

The problem is that the `actionPerformed` function still eats all my events when clicked in the area where the previously hidden buttons are. How can I solve this nicely?

**EDIT SSCCE:**
For a full working example (under 400 lines of Java) please download my example project 
Download link (please report if any problems occur): http://wikisend.com/download/307016/jLevel.zip
You can use the provided makefile if you wish (I also attached a compiled version). The game can be run using the run.bash file (Windows users have to run it manually, usage: java GameMain [screen width] [screen height] [bit depth]).

Now how to replicate the problem:

- Run the game from the console
- You can click around a little bit (not on the buttons!) and you won't see any messages in the console.
- Now click the **`Resume game`** button. The following message is posted to the console: `ActionEvent caught in Menu class`. This is good.
- Now just click around and for every click you will get the message: `MouseEvent caught in InputManager class`. This is also fine.
- Now, remember where the buttons are located? Click there and no message appears, they are still caught by the `actionPerformed()` function in the `Menu` class. The problem is basically how I can pass these messages to my `InputManager` class, so that they can be used inside the game.

**Buttons will be restored after 10 seconds, so you can use the `Exit game` button to close the application.**

**IF YOU DO NOT WANT TO DOWNLOAD YOU CAN COPY-PASTE THE NEEDED FILES FROM HERE**

**`GameMain.java`**

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public final class GameMain extends JFrame
{
    public long ticker = 0;

    public static ScreenManager screenManager;

    // Managing keyboard and mouse input
    public static InputManager inputManager;
    // Main menu
    public static Menu mainMenu;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new GameMain(args);
    }


    private GameMain(String[] args)
    {
        DisplayMode displayMode = new DisplayMode(Integer.parseInt(args[0]) /* width */,
                              Integer.parseInt(args[1]) /* heigth */,
                              Integer.parseInt(args[2]) /* bit depth */,
                              DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN /* refresh rate */);

        screenManager = ScreenManager.getInstance();
        if (!screenManager.setFullScreen(displayMode, this));
        // Prevent Swing from drawing its own components
        RepaintManagerResetter.resetRepaintManager();

        mainMenu = new Menu(false);
        inputManager = InputManager.createInstance(screenManager.getFullScreenWindow());

        for (;;)
        {
            if (ticker % 200 == 0) // Bring buttons back
            {
                mainMenu.blockActionEvents(false);
                inputManager.setBlocking(true);
            }

            Graphics2D screenGraphics = screenManager.getGraphics();
            draw(screenGraphics);
            screenGraphics.dispose();
            screenManager.updateGraphicsDisplay();
            try { Thread.sleep(50); ++ticker;} catch (Exception ex){}
        }
    }

    // Draw game game graphics
    private void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, screenManager.getWidth(), screenManager.getHeight());

        // Draw
        if (showMainMenu())
        {
            mainMenu.drawComponents(g);
        }
        else
        {
            // Draw game
            g.drawString("Do interesting stuff", 200, 200);
        }
    }

    public static boolean showMainMenu()
    {
        return !mainMenu.isBlocked();
    }
}
```

**`ScreenManager.java`**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;


public class ScreenManager
{
    private static ScreenManager screenManager;

    private GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice;


    protected ScreenManager()
    {
        GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        graphicsDevice = graphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    }


    public static ScreenManager getInstance()
    {
        if (screenManager == null)
        {
            screenManager = new ScreenManager();
        }
        return screenManager;
    }


    public boolean setFullScreen(DisplayMode displayMode, JFrame hwnd)
    {
        hwnd.setUndecorated(true);
        hwnd.setResizable(true);
        hwnd.setVisible(true);
        hwnd.setIgnoreRepaint(true);

        graphicsDevice.setFullScreenWindow(hwnd);

        if (displayMode != null && graphicsDevice.isDisplayChangeSupported())
        {
            try
            {
                graphicsDevice.setDisplayMode(displayMode);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("WARNING: Could not set the screen to desired display mode: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Accessing graphics device failed.");
            return false;
        }

        /* Create buffer strategy for the window */
        hwnd.createBufferStrategy(2);

        return true;
    }


    public DisplayMode[] getDisplayModes()
    {
        return graphicsDevice.getDisplayModes();
    }


    public Window getFullScreenWindow()
    {
        return graphicsDevice.getFullScreenWindow();
    }


    public BufferStrategy getBufferStrategy()
    {
        return getFullScreenWindow().getBufferStrategy();
    }


    public Graphics2D getGraphics()
    {
        return (Graphics2D) getBufferStrategy().getDrawGraphics();
    }


    public int getWidth()
    {
        return getFullScreenWindow().getWidth();
    }


    public int getHeight()
    {
        return getFullScreenWindow().getHeight();
    }


    public void updateGraphicsDisplay()
    {
        BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = getBufferStrategy();
        if (!bufferStrategy.contentsLost())
        {
            bufferStrategy.show();
        }

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }
}
```

**`Menu.Java`**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Menu implements ActionListener
{
    protected boolean blocked;

    protected ScreenManager screenManager;
    protected JFrame menuWindow;
    protected Container contentPane;

    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JButton startButton;
    private JButton stopButton;


    public Menu(boolean blocked)
    {
        this.blocked = blocked;

        screenManager = GameMain.screenManager;
        menuWindow = (JFrame) screenManager.getFullScreenWindow();

        /* Make sure content pane is transparent */
        contentPane = menuWindow.getContentPane();
        if (contentPane instanceof JComponent)
        {
            ((JComponent) contentPane).setOpaque(false);
        }

        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 50, screenManager.getHeight() / 2));

        startButton = createGUIButton("Resume game");
        stopButton = createGUIButton("Exit game");
        panel.add(startButton);
        panel.add(stopButton);
        contentPane.add(panel);

        menuWindow.validate();
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (!blocked)
        {
            Object source = e.getSource();

            if (stopButton == (JButton) source)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else if (startButton == (JButton) source)
            {
                blockActionEvents(true);
                GameMain.inputManager.setBlocking(false);
            }
            System.out.println("ActionEvent caught in Menu class");
        }
    }


    public void drawComponents(Graphics g)
    {
        menuWindow.getLayeredPane().paintComponents(g);
    }


    protected JButton createGUIButton(String text)
    {
        /* Set button attributes */
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        return button;
    }


    public void blockActionEvents(boolean blocked)
    {
        this.blocked = blocked;
    }


    public boolean isBlocked()
    {
        return blocked;
    }
}
```

**`RepaintManagerResetter.java`**

```
import javax.swing.RepaintManager;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class RepaintManagerResetter extends RepaintManager
{
    public static void resetRepaintManager()
    {
        RepaintManager repaintManager = new RepaintManagerResetter();
        repaintManager.setDoubleBufferingEnabled(false);
        repaintManager.setCurrentManager(repaintManager);
    }


    public void addInvalidComponent(JComponent c)
    {
    }

    public void addDirtyRegion(JComponent c, int x, int y, int w, int h)
    {
    }

    public void markCompletelyDirty(JComponent c)
    {
    }

    public void paintDirtyRegions()
    {
    }
}
```

**`InputManager.java`**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class InputManager implements KeyListener, MouseListener
{
    private static InputManager inputManager;
    private boolean blocking;

    private Component inputManagerComponent;


    protected InputManager(Component inputManagerComponent)
    {
        this.inputManagerComponent = inputManagerComponent;

        /* Register listeners */
        inputManagerComponent.addKeyListener(this);
        inputManagerComponent.addMouseListener(this);
        inputManagerComponent.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }


    public static InputManager createInstance(Component inputManagerComponent)
    {
        if (inputManager == null)
        {
            inputManager = new InputManager(inputManagerComponent);
        }
        return inputManager;
    }


    public boolean isBlocking()
    {
        return blocking;
    }


    public void setBlocking(boolean blocking)
    {
        this.blocking = blocking;
    }


    public static InputManager getInstance()
    {
        return inputManager;
    }


    /****** Keyboard events ******/

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (blocking) return;
        // Do stuff
        e.consume();
    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (blocking) return;
        // Do stuff
        e.consume();
    }


    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (blocking) return;
        // Do stuff
        e.consume();
    }



    /****** Mouse events ******/

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (blocking) return;
        // Do stuff
        e.consume();
    }


    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (blocking) return;
        // Do stuff
        e.consume();
    }


    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (blocking) return;
        // Do stuff
        System.out.println("MouseEvent caught in InputManager class");
        e.consume();
    }



    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }
}
```

**`makefile`**

```
PROJECTNAME = test
CC = javac
CLASS_FILES = GameMain.class ScreenManager.class InputManager.class Menu.class RepaintManagerResetter.class


jLevel: $(CLASS_FILES)
    @echo Done.

%.class : %.java
    @echo Compiling $*.java to $@ [command: $(CC) $*.java ] ...
    $(CC) -source 6 -Xlint:unchecked $*.java

clean:
    @rm $(CLASS_FILES)
    @echo Cleaned...
```

**`run.bash`**

```
#!/bin/bash
STARUP_CLASS="GameMain"
ARGUMENTS="1280 1024 -1"
java $STARUP_CLASS $ARGUMENTS
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: If I want to try the code, testing solutions, I have no intention of going the 'extra mile (inch, centimeter ..whatever) by turning that into a class.  There are a lot of other reasons, but I'm too lazy to add them..  So post an SSCCE or rely on everybody who is willing to try & answer your question without one to do so.  Your call.

Comment: "**EDIT SSCCE:** Download: .. (is too large to post here,.."  (Sigh) I often wonder whether people read anything beyond the first word in the description of the SSCCE.  Seems you were not even able to get that far.

Comment: *"But trimming the code further than this will cost be quite a lot of time."*  I presume by 'be' you mean 'me'.  1) OK - wait and see how long it takes you so solve when everyone ignores you. 2) You are complaining about how it will cost you time, but did it ever cross your mind that the people who are offering help, for free, might value ***their own time*** as well?  -- This is discussed in the document.

Comment: *"I have updated it and it is an acceptable amount of code"*  Acceptable to you maybe.  I will help when you post an *SSCCE* as an edit to the question.  Note that 1) 400 LOC would not be considered 'short' by most people. 2) *"(250Kb) because of the included sample button images.."* Images?  WTF do images have to do with event listeners? Use buttons with no icon, and if it requires more than 1 button, have it include 2 buttons (as opposed 3 or 10).

Comment: *"If you actually tested the application"*  My download allocation for each month is not enough that I am willing to download 1/4 Meg. of code/images.

Comment: *"that is like 20 non-cached pages of SO."*  What makes you presume I browse SO with 'show images' enabled?  You take a lot for granted.  BTW - in case I did not make it clear in any earlier comment, I will not download ***any*** zip file of ***any*** size.  Make an SSCCE and put it in the question.

Comment: Can you please remove the full-screen requirement, I find it hard to debug with that.

Comment: Hey @Jori, I answered your question!!! And the solution works!! You may have to manually award the bounty, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple modification to the `Menu` class as follows:

```
public class Menu implements ActionListener
{
    ...

    public Menu(boolean blocked)
    {
        // this.blocked = blocked;

        ...

        startButton = createGUIButton("Resume game");
        stopButton = createGUIButton("Exit game");
        panel.add(startButton);
        panel.add(stopButton);
        // contentPane.add(panel);

        // menuWindow.validate();
        blockActionListeners(blocked); // added this line
    }

    ...

    public void blockActionEvents(boolean blocked)
    {
        this.blocked = blocked;
        if (blocked) {  // added from here...
                contentPane.remove(panel);
                menuWindow.validate();
        } else {
                contentPane.add(panel);
                menuWindow.validate();
        } // to here
    }

    ...
}
```

Added lines are indicated by a comment, and removed lines are simply commented out.

This modification is simply to remove the buttons when they are supposed to be invisible, instead of just not painting them. If you just don't paint them, the events will still go to the buttons. I tested this solution, and it works.